# Lista anidadas en python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista que inicialmente puede venir así `list = ['a','b','c','d',...]` o con mas o menos elementos dentro de ella, es decir que puede variar, incluso puede venir un elemento vacío ''.

Yo esa lista la quiero anidar a algo así `list = [['a','b'],['c','d'],...]`

he intentando hacerlo con una compresión de lista a algo así:

```
y = [[j for j in list] for i in list[0::2]]
```

y me devuelve la anidación y separación pero de cada elemento pero así:

```
salida: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

No se como separarla por cada dos elementos anidados en la lista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto `range` que vaya desde cero hasta el valor de la longitud de `list_`, de dos en dos. Luego, iterar sobre ese objeto `range` e ir rebanando `list_` en pares de elementos, por cada iteración.

Es decir:

```
>>> list_ = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> [list_[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(list_), 2)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

**otra solución** (siempre y cuando no te importe que en vez de listas anidadas sean tuplas dentro de listas), es usar `zip` como se muestra a continuación:

```
>>> list_ = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> [*zip(list_[::2], list_[1::2])]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

---

Pro tip: No sobreescribas los nombres de los elementos builtins de Python (como `list`). Colócales un underscore al final y listo.

Comment: Esta solucion es mucho mas elegante (aunque desde mi punto de vista un poco menos legible), esta mejor que la mia ...

Comment: Gracias, @PySanti Es un gusto verte empezando a responder ahora preguntas. Y sí, no es lo más legible del mundo, debo admitir.

Comment: @revliscano otra forma podría ser: [[list_[x],list_[x+1]] for x in range(0,len(list_),2)] quizá sea más "legible"

Comment: Sí, @tincopasan es válida tu acotación. Así OP tiene más margen de dónde escoger según sus gustos o necesidades.

Answer (score 4):

Bien, por lo que entiendo la idea es separar una lista en otra matriz donde las columnas sean los numeros impares en la primera lista, en otras palabras, partir una lista(1) en varias sublistas de dos elementos que se vayan insertando en otra lista(2). En ese caso podrias hacer algo asi ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

def generador_de_dos_elementos_de_una_lista(lista : list[str]) -> list:
    i = 0
    while i < len(lista):
        yield [lista[i], lista[i+1]]
        i += 2

es_par = lambda x : (x%2 == 0)


lista_1 = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']
lista_2 = []
if not es_par(len(lista_1)) or (len(lista_1) == 0):
    print('Longitud de lista invalida (^ _ ^) ')
else:
    for sublista in generador_de_dos_elementos_de_una_lista(lista_1):
        lista_2.append( sublista)
    print(lista_2)
```

Nota: esto solo funciona en python3.9 ya que estoy usando [GenericAlias](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type), por otro lado, solo funciona en caso de que la longitud de la lista sea par y que no este vacia, ya que mencionaste que la idea es partir la primera lista en sublistas de dos elementos...

Comment: Es una solución innecesariamente complicada. El código se puede acortar usando python estándar.

Comment: @CandidMoe complicado no, largo tal vez. Trate de hacerla lo mas legible posible. Ciertamente hay muchas formas de hacerlo en 2 lineas (como lo hizo revliscano por ejemplo)

Comment: Yo doy +1 por la legibilidad.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la respuesta de @PySanti se puede acortar y hacer valida para todas las versiones soportadas de Python.

El código quedaría así:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def generador_de_dos_elementos_de_una_lista(lista) -> list:
    for i in range(0, len(lista), 2):
        yield [lista[i], lista[i+1]]

lista_1 = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']

if not lista_1 or len(lista_1) % 2:
    print('Longitud de lista invalida (^ _ ^) ')
else:
    lista_2 = [sublista for sublista in generador_de_dos_elementos_de_una_lista(lista_1)]
    print(lista_2)
```

En el generador use el `for` con `step=2` para recorrer la lista de dos en dos, evitando el manejo manual del indice.

Las funciones lambda se ocupan para evitar tener que definir una función separada usando `def`. En este caso, simplemente tenemos que chequear que el largo de la lista sea par, lo que podemos hacer directamente en el `if`.

El `if` lo podemos simplificar. En Python, una lista vacía es `False`, por lo que no es necesario comparar su largo contra cero.

Finalmente, en lugar de un `for` para armar la lista final usando `append`, use una comprensión de listas, que es más corto y rápido.

Probablemente haya otras optimizaciones ...

Comment: una pregunta, el yield para que sirve en este caso?

Comment: @NJesus. El `yield x` es como un `return x` pero sigues procesando. En otras palabras, le mandas un valor al llamante, pero sigues ejecutando dentro de la función. Cuando finalmente retornas, el llamante ve que se acabaron los datos.

Answer (score 3):

La [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) de python sugiere el uso del paquete `more-itertools` para extender las capacidades del paquete estandar `itertools`. Basado en la implementación proporcionada por este módulo y de una simplificación en su interfaz, la solución sería:

```py
from functools import partial
from itertools import islice

def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

def chunked(n, iterable):
    "Break *iterable* into lists of length *n*"
    return iter(partial(take, n, iter(iterable)), [])

lista = ['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f']
print(list(chunked(2, lista)))
```

Su funcionamiento es bastante sencillo una vez que entiendes la idea. La función `chunked` empieza definiendo una función parcial `partial(take, n, iter(iterable)` que va ser usada como un iterable, es por eso que se define `iter(partial(...), [])` que se traduciría en `partial(...)` es un iterable que tiene como valor centinela, o como valor final `[]`, es decir que `iter` va consumir elementos de `partial(...)` hasta que este retorne `[]`.

Es importante hacer distinción entre el comportamiento de `iter(...)` con un valor centinela especificado en su segundo argumento y un llamado sin este. Si la función `iter` no recibé un valor centinela entonces se generan las siguientes situaciones:

1. La función retorna un objeto iterador sobre el objeto que fue pasado como argumento (puede ser él mismo si es un iterable self-iterator)
2. Si el objeto no tiene implementado el protocolo de iterable/iterador, es decir el método `__iter__`, y `__next__` o `__getitem__` entonces se lanza una excepción.

En contraparte cuando la función `iter` recibe el valor centinela como segundo argumento, este retorna un iterable que ya no requiere la implementación del protocolo iterable/iterador, en su lugar llama el objeto `callable` proporcionado como primer argumento (puede ser una función o un objeto con el método `__call__` implementado) en cada paso de iteración, hasta que este retorne el valor centinela.

Una vez explicado lo anterior, la función `chunked` lo que hace es prácticamente llamar la función `take` con los argumentos `n` e `iterable` hasta que este regrese `[]`, al ser un iterable el argumento `iterable` de la función `take` (valga la redundancia), cada vez que esta es llamada, consume `n` elementos del iterable (a través de `list(islice(iterable, n))`) y los retorna como lista, la siguiente vez que esta función sea llamada ya se abran consumido `n` elementos anteriores y dara el comportamiento esperando que es de un desplazamiento de `n` elementos en cada paso.

Un comportamiento que tiene esta función es que si la cantidad de elementos en el iterable no es `múltiplo` de `n`, entonces la última lista retornada tendrá menos elementos que las demas. Si deseas que todas las listas retornadas tengan los mismos elementos a través de rellenar  los espacios vacíos de la última lista entonces puedes checar la implementación de la función `grouper` en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

> **Nota.** La razón principal del uso de iterables es principalmente para hacer uso responsable de la memoria.

Comment: Esta respuesta es brillante desde el punto de vista del manejo del lenguaje. Si pudiera destildar la mía como "aceptada", lo haría para aceptar esta.